# Mover sprite até a posição do mouse com Phaser

Tags: javascript, canvas, game, phaser-js

Preciso mover um sprite para a posição do mouse, utilizei a função `game.physics.arcade.moveToPointer()`, mas só funciona com `sprites` que têm o corpo do tipo `Phaser.Physics.Arcade`.

Como faço para utilizar esta função usando um corpo do tipo `Phaser.Physics.P2JS`? https://codepen.io/salomaosnff/pen/LQXWPv

Answer (score 0):

existe este método:

```
update() {
    this.player.x = game.input.x;
    this.player.y = game.input.y;
}
```

Comment: Eu até tentei desta forma, mas assim não consego ajustar alguns parâmetros como a velocidade.
A melhor solução que encontrei foi reescrevendo as funções moveToPointer, distanceToPointer e angleToPointer em um arquivo separado.